# How to change the style of the title of an action submenu?

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar, styles, title

How can I change the color and the font size of this title through the style.xml file?

[image]

Just to know, is there an easy way to hide it?

Answer (score -1):

Try the below code in your `onCreateOptionsMenu`

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.your_menu, menu);

    int positionOfMenuItem = 0; // or whatever...
    MenuItem item = menu.getItem(positionOfMenuItem);
    SpannableString s = new SpannableString("Configuration");
    s.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, s.length(), 0); // changes color to red
    s.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(1.5f), 0, end, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE); // changes font size
    item.setTitle(s);
}
```

or if you want to change the style of the entire menu

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuInflater awesome = getMenuInflater();
    awesome.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    for(int i = 0; i < menu.size(); i++) {
        MenuItem item = menu.getItem(i);
        SpannableString spanString = new SpannableString(menu.getItem(i).getTitle().toString());
        int end = spanString.length();
        spanString.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(1.5f), 0, end, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        item.setTitle(spanString);
    }
    return true;
}
```